# How to Hibernate annotate Map<String, Set<String>> or Map<String, Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

*using Hibernate Core 4.1.7, JPA annotations, java 1.7*

Easy to fine are examples about Map<String, Entity> reading Hibernate [doc on collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/collections.html), or Map<String, String> [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946987/mapping-mapstring-string-using-hibernate).

Hard to find are examples on `Map<String, Set<String>>` (or even Map<String, Map<String, String>> just for curiosity about daisy chaning) why I ask this question here.

All I want is to save entities (accounts) containing named, multi-valued properties (=account attributes).

I have all working with 3 entity types: `Account -> @OneToMany -> AccountAttribute -> @OneToMany -> AccountAttributeValue`

But wrapping native Java types with my own Classes **seems a bit silly** to me. Cloning the Map<String, String> example I would like to have something like

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="key")
    private Long key;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Attribute",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fkAccount"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    // next line is working for Map<String, String>, but not here!
    @Column(name = "value")  
    private Map<String, Set<String>> attributes = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    // ... omitting: constructor, getters, setters, toString()

}
```

Which gives me
`Initial SessionFactory creation failed: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not  determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Attribute, for columns:[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(attributes)]`

As DB layout I have created 2 Tables. 
 - Table `Account` just having a key to point foreign key to
 - Table `Attribute` containing named value in each line.

E.g. for **multivalued attributes** I thought of it containing **2 lines** with same `fkAccount` and `name` but different `value` - yes, I could have normalized even more, but I want to read my data in acceptable time :-)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo`.`Account` (
  `key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  ...

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo`.`Attribute` (
  `fkAccount` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
  ...
```

Any hints or alternate DB layout proposals appreciated.

**EDIT - SOLVED**
Solution from Tom (as far as I understood) working for me
Thanky you guys, what an experience, solution in 1 day!

The table layout just mentioned above in my question works now with this classes.

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    /* ... omitting "key", see as above */

    /* NEW: now @CollectionTable 
            replaces @JoinTable / @MapKeyColumn / @Column  from above
    */
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="AccountAttribute",
                     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fkAccount"))
    private Set<AccountAttribute> attributes = null;

    // ... omitting: constructor, getters, setters, toString()
}
```

and NEW

```
    @Embeddable
    public class AccountAttribute {

        @Column(name="attributeName")
        private String attributeName = null;

        @Column(name="attributeValue")
        private String attributeValue = null;

        // ... omitting: constructor, getters, setters, toString()
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect the contents of the Set to be in a separate table (eg AttributeValues or something) with a row per value, or do you want the Set to be serialized somehow in to the Attribute.value column?

Comment: yes, multi-valued attributes having 2 lines with same name, different values, see the solution I chose. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA doesn't give you any way to map collections of collections of anything. You can map primitives, references to entities, embeddables, and collections of any of the preceding things.

Collection there means a set, list, or map; there isn't a multimap type here which would help you.

Therefore, there is sadly no way to map exactly the structure you want to map.

I think the closest you could come would be to define an embeddable class `Attribute`, containing a name and a value, then map a `Set<Attribute>`. You could then convert this to a `Map<String, Set<String>>` in code.

It's a shame there's no way to do this. I assume the JPA spec authors either didn't think of it, or thought it was an obscure enough corner case that it wasn't worth dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for your answering time! Hard to decide between sharakan and Tom Anderson. Finally, I took Tom being shorter and straight forward.
I'll update my post with the solution

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to model this in the database, and it comes down to how many tables you want.  If you want three, then the way you have working is basically right, although you could trim it to two entities (`Account` and `AccountAttribute`) where `AccountAttribute` contains a Set of values.

You can't model it with three tables and just an Account entity, because you don't have enough identifiers.  The `VALUE` table would have to have a compound key made up of the account id and some kind of attribute key, your tables would have to look like:

```
ACCOUNT (id, ...)
ACCOUNT_ATTRIBUTE(account_id, account_attribute_id, ...)
ACCOUNT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE(account_id, account_attribute_id, value, ...)
```

if `AccountAttribute` is an entity, then it has an ID.  If not, it doesn't, and so how would you key the `ACCOUNT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE` table?

This is borne out by the JPA spec, as mentioned in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261659/is-it-possible-for-a-jpa-embeddable-to-contain-embeddable-or-collection-of-embed).

Now, you COULD do this in two tables with just an `Account` entity, by collapsing that Set in to some serialized form and persisting it as binary, or XML, or whatever.  Not sure if that's worth the effort to you, but the column you sketched out (`value varchar(45)`) is almost certainly not long enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answering time! Hard to decide between sharakan and Tom Anderson. Finally, I took Tom being shorter and straight forward.
@sharakan, thank you indeed for putting the solutions 2/3 table next to each other, which clarified things for me. I chose not to encode/decode a multivalue into one column cause I am afraid of performance/searching issues when searching the xml in the column.

Comment: @hokr my pleasure.  fyi, on SO you can upvote answers that were helpful, even if you decided to accept another one (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote/130047#130047)

Comment: Thanks for the hint and here is your merits. I somehow "thought" ticking the green checkmark is enough - dont aks me why :-)